# Which RFID standards can be read by an NFC reader on an Android phone?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I want to make an RFID reader using the NFC chip inside an Android mobile phone, say the Galaxy S3. After some Googling, I have found that Android supports a few NFC tag technologies and that some of them are RFID standards also.

Android supports the following NFC tag technologies:

TagTechnology - The interface that all tag technology classes must implement.

NfcA - Provides access to NFC-A (ISO 14443-3A) properties and I/O operations.

NfcB - Provides access to NFC-B (ISO 14443-3B) properties and I/O operations.

NfcF - Provides access to NFC-F (JIS 6319-4) properties and I/O operations.

NfcV - Provides access to NFC-V (ISO 15693) properties and I/O operations.

IsoDep - Provides access to ISO-DEP (ISO 14443-4) properties and I/O operations.

Ndef - Provides access to NDEF data and operations on NFC tags that have been formatted as NDEF.

NdefFormatable - Provides a format operations for tags that may be NDEF formattable.

**What I want to know is which of the above are RFID standards which an RFID reader is supposed to support?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HF (13.56 MHz) tags should theoretically work, UHF won't work. Not sure how compatible the API is, but you should be able to at least get the ID with `Tag.getId()`. Get one of the popular tag reader apps and try your tags. If the app can read them, you should be able to do the same. What tags do you want to use?